# Sound reduction window/glasses: What reduces sound?

Tags: acoustics, glass

Hello Physics community,

I have a small question regarding noise reduction windows.

May I ask what helps reduce sound wave please?

Is it the thickness of the glass? I see some windows with different sizes of glasses. My inexperience would make me say the thicker the better to reduce sound. Is it?

Is it the number of glasses? I see some windows with one glass, two glasses, and up to three glasses. My inexperience would make me say the more glasses the better. But how much does it helps?

What between air or glue reduces the most sound wave please? Sometimes, the panels of glasses are separated by air, or emptiness. Sometimes, they are glued together. In which scenario it reduces sound more please??

Thank you for your time

Comment: I started writing an answer but then realised that this post is a duplicate. [Why is sound reflected and not transmitted through a wall?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/236063/why-is-sound-reflected-and-not-transmitted-through-a-wall/236071#236071).  With double glazing the effect is enhanced because there is an increase in the number of discontinuities.

Comment: Hello Farcher, many thanks for your comment. I don't think it is really a duplicate, since I am also interesting in the material of the windows itself. Also, I am quite interested in your opinion, maybe you can just post your draft please?

Comment: What about [CBD-240. Sound Transmission Through Windows](https://nrc-publications.canada.ca/eng/view/ft/?id=5468d3d7-d326-4d2a-9e80-ecc8b5bec651)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the gap between the glass panes is the most important factor for noise reduction.

From [this link](https://clearviewsg.co.uk/acoustic/noise-reduction-secondary-glazing/) we see:

"The wider the gap, the better the sound insulation. Where possible, we recommend an air gap of between 100mm-150mm for acoustic insulation (200mm if you have the space). The air gap is more important than the glass and will do the lion share of the sound reduction."

They then also mention the type of glass, but say it's not an important factor, also to ensure there are no gaps around the frames, but that's also not as important as the gap between the panes of glass.

Many homes have double glazing, for heat insulation, but the best gap for that is about 1.6cm - that gap reduces conduction, but any more allows convection currents to form.

So triple glazing is the answer if you want good heat insulation and noise reduction.  It then has two gaps, a large gap for the noise and a 16mm gap for the heat insulation.

Comment: Very clear, and appreciate the link

Comment: that's good, all the best